# rename directory(error Could not find a part of the path.)

Tags: c#

```
string sourceDir = @"E:\Images\3\2\1";
string destDir = @"E:\Images\33\22\11";
Directory.Move(sourceDir, destinationDir);
```

I have to rename directory I use Directory.Move() but gives me error:

```
Could not find a part of the path.
```

Comment: Does the folder 22 and 33 exist?

Comment: No......................

Comment: Well then it's clear why the error occurs, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Folder, to which you are moving, should exist before you move.

Call `Directory.Create([path to target folder]`) before `Directory.Move`

Comment: but inside folder 1 there are files so  i ahve to move that files to  11 Directory using Directory.Move it work or not

Comment: Files will be moved with the directory.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in `string destDir = @"E:\Images\33\22\11";` Images\33\22\ does not exist. You cannot create new subdirectories using `Directory.Move`, so `E:\Images\33\22\` must already exist.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make sure that the location you are moving the folder to aleady exists. To make it easy you could do something like the following.

Basically you need to make sure that the path where you are moving the file to exists.

```
string sourceDir = @"E:\Images\3\2\1";
string destName = "1";
string destDir = @"E:\Images\33\22\";

Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir); // Create the location path
Directory.Move(sourceDir, Path.Combine(destDir + destName));
```

**Edit:** Added basic error handling.

This is an example with basic error handling to make sure that both the source and destination directory exists.

```
string sourceDir = @"E:\Images\3\2\1";
string destName = "1";
string destDir = @"E:\Images\33\22\";

if (!Directory.Exists(sourceDir))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Source Directory does not exist.");
    Console.Read();
    //return; // Handle issue where Source Dir does not exist.
}

if (!Directory.Exists(destDir))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Destination Directory does exist. Created.");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir);
}

if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(destDir + destName)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Target Destination already exist.");
    Console.Read();
    return;
}

Directory.Move(sourceDir, Path.Combine(destDir + destName));
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Could not find a part of the path.

Comment: Did you edit my code? It's important that you write `E:\Images\33\22` for the `destDir`, not `E:\Images\33\22\11`.

Comment: @Means Also make sure that `E:\Images\3\2\1` exists. If you ran any of the previously posted code.

Comment: there are some files inside Directory 1 @"E:\Images\3\2\1..So ihave to move all the files to Directory 11

Comment: @Means Run the latest code I attached and please provide me with the output. Please, also attach any changes you did to `sourceDir` and `destDir`.

Comment: Can you post the changes you did to my code? The exact variables you use for sourceDir, destDir and destName.

Comment: string sourceDir = @"E:\Images\3\2\1";
string destDir = @"E:\Images\33\22\11";

Comment: I have to rename Directory 1 with 11 but files in Directory 1 also moved to Directory 11

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26940/discussion-between-means-and-eandersson)